# Android: Make parent selector trigger when selecting child

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout with some other LinearLayouts inside. The children layouts have a background selector set. I need to change the color of the parent layout as well when a children is pressed. I have set a background selector as well for the parent, but it only triggers when clicking outside of any children.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try adding this to the layout attributes for the parent LinearLayout:

```
android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
```

Alternatively, in code call:

```
parentLayout.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
```

In either case, be sure that the child layouts do *not* have the `android:duplicateParentState` attribute set (and do not call `setDuplicateParentState(true)`), or you will get an exception at run time when the system detects the circular dependency.

Comment: How would you do the opposite: trigger the selector of the child when touching the container ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - You could use `android:duplicateParentState` in the child. The child would then use its parent drawable state instead of its own. The parent would then have to be clickable, selectable, or whatever you needed the child to be.

Comment: I see. is it possible to set the selector on top? also, is there a different solution for listView items (where each item is a layout with a view as i've written here) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - I don't understand what you mean by "set the selector on top". As far as a listview row, you'd use the same solution: set the child to duplicate the parent state; then when the row is selected, the child (assuming it is just one level down) will display in a selected state.

Comment: I'm talking about doing it like on the play store (when you click on an item). the listView has an attribute that sets the selector to be on top of the item instead of the background, which is called "drawSelectorOnTop" .

Comment: anyway, i've made a thread about it (here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588662/how-to-trigger-selectors-from-the-layout-view ), and the answer is based on :http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/07/17/adding-a-foreground-selector-to-a-view/ . thanks for trying to help.